# How to show Jquery UI autocomplete widgets on autocomplete() method?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm hoping someone can help with this, 
 I'm having a really difficult time getting jQueryUI's autocomplete to work with **$.ajax({})** call in an asp.net application.
 I can get it to make the ajax call, am getting response from service and the list of the locations. 
but still the autocomplete list is not shown, when I press the down arrow key then location list is rendered on the page. 
It should be rendered/shown immediately after getting the list of locations from web method. How could it be possible?

I'm using autocomplete from jquery site: **http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/**

Sample Code

```
function GetCitiesLikeList(objcity) {    
var cities = "";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: http://localhost/testweb/location.asmx/Getlocations,
            data: "{ City : '" + objcity + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg.d != null && msg.d != "") {
                    cities = "";
                    cities = msg.d;
                    $("#citilist").autocomplete({
                        source: cities
                    });
                }
                else
                    $("#citilist").attr("autocomplete", "off")
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { return false; }
        }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way to trigger the jQuery UI autocomplete functionality, without typing into the box:

```
$('#field').autocomplete({
    source: '/path/to/data',
    minLength: 0
});
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#field').autocomplete('search', '')
});
```

Sending the 'search' arg triggers the search functionality. The second argument is the "term" sent to the data handler at /path/to/data.

Comment: ya you are also doing well.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To show the list just call `$('#citilist').trigger("keydown");`
This makes it think you are typing in the citilist input, and will trigger the ajax post.

Comment: Thanks @ariel It will fired event and getting results but I have other problem when I press keydown then I getting previous query results in autocomplete list. for example: I try to search 'los ang' then it get all locations related to 'los ang*' then I deleted all value and try to write 'mexi' then it shown me previous reults.. how to remove or flush previous results from it..

Comment: i guess you need to call GetCitiesLikeList() before the trigger.

Comment: I believe it's working like this -> GetCitiesLikeList -> Trigger -> success. So when you trigger the list haven't returned yet. So you have to trigger in the success method.

Comment: @ariel I called in success method.. like =>                           success: function (msg) {
                if (msg.d != null && msg.d != "") {
                    cities = "";
                    cities = msg.d;
                    $("#citilist").autocomplete({
                        source: cities
                    });
                    $('#citilist').trigger("keydown");
                }
                else
                    $("#citilist").attr("autocomplete", "off")
            },

Answer (score 0):

Jquery autocomplete is triggered only when a key is struck, That's what is happening with you. That's the functionality it is designed for. If you want to customise that. You should write your own logic.